# Increment counter every time textarea text is wrapped

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx, scenebuilder

I need to be able to count a line every time text is wrapped.  I am using the javaFX "TextArea" control.

I have implemented a counter that is incremented every time a "\n" character is encountered. Unfortunately, this ignores the additional lines created due to text wrapping.

There *IS* a way to circumvent this using the jtextarea swing control, which is similar to javafx's text area, but I don't really want to use it because the FX version has other pieces of functionality which are much better suited to my tasks.

If anyone has any suggestions about how to increment this counter, please let me know! Alternatively, another way to count lines would be just as effective.

(I'm using scene builder 2.0 in conjunction with Netbeans 8.1/8.0.2 (both))

I had to manually put in the newline characters as follows:

```
String pText = Primary.getText();
        Primary.clear();

                     StringReader reader = new StringReader(pText);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader); 
            //FileReader reader = new FileReader(fileLocation);
            //BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader); 
            String s;
            int index = 0;
            //int charCounter = 0;

            boolean endOfPara = false;


//                                        int index = 0;
//                                                    boolean endOfPara = false;
      try{                                           
            //loads the text and formats it if necessary                                        
            while((s = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                index = 0;

                //loading block
                if(s.length() <= characterCapacity)
                {
                    //String s = "abcdefg";
                    int result = s.indexOf('\n');

                    if(result == -1)
                    {
                        Primary.appendText(s + "\n");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Primary.appendText(s);
                    }
                }
                //formatting block
                else
                {
                    while(index < s.length()) //change this
                    {

                            if((index == characterCapacity) && (index < s.length() - 1))
                            {
                                while(s.charAt(index) != ' ')
                                {
                                    index--;
                                }   

                                String n = s.substring(0, index);
                                s = s.substring(index);

                                //if(n.charAt(n.length() - 1) == '\n')
                                //{
                                //    Primary.appendText(n);
                                //}
                                //else
                                //{
                                    Primary.appendText(n + "\n");
                                //}

                                index = 0;
                            }
                            else if((index == s.length() - 1) && (index <= characterCapacity) && (s.length() > 0))
                            {
                                Primary.appendText(s + "\n");
                                index = s.length();  //OR use break;
                                endOfPara = true;

                                Primary.forward();
                                Primary.deletePreviousChar();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                index++;
                            }

                            /*if(charCounter > 90)
                            {
                                if((charCounter >= 90) && (s.charAt(index) != )
                                {

                                }

                                if(index == (s.length() - 1))
                                {

                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    charCounter++;
                                }
                            }*/
                    }

                    /*if(endOfPara == true)
                {
                    if(s.charAt(index - 2) != '\n')
                    {
                        Primary.appendText("\n");
                    }
                }

                endOfPara = false;*/

                }




            }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {}
```

I had a previous version of this which worked A LOT better, but unfortunately, it would insert newline characters in the middle of words, in some cases.

So yeah, in a nutshell, this is why I want to use a third party library to "get row number"/"get total rows", or find some way to do it using textarea skin.

Please Help! I am really stuck on this...

Comment: show us what you have done so far.....

Comment: Here it is:) Any ideas on how to get around this messy approach?